# How to properly store big values in parallel SRAM

Tags: measurement, high-frequency

For a project I need to determine the frequency and phase-shift of up to 16 channels. The frequency range is **0 to 3 kHz** and the signalform is square.

My first idea was to use the following circuit to save the signals into a memory IC (SRAM):

[image]

(**CTR** = 16 Bit Address Counter, **TMR** = 21/32 Bit Timer)

The input channels IN are sampled on each positive CLK cycle.
If an edge occurred, the address counter is incremented and the WR (Write Enable) bit is set.

Then on the negative CLK cycle the SRAM is going to be active and saves the data if the WR bit was set.

The timer TMR is always incremented on each positive CLK cycle.

The sampling frequency (CLK) should be **20Mhz** and the measurement period is **100ms**:

Gives a 2'000'000 max. value for the timer: **I need at least 21 bits to store the timer value**:

21 Bits (timer) + 16 Bits (channels) = 37 Bits

But the data bus of the SRAM is only **32** bits wide so I need at least two write cycles to accomplish my task. I don't want to decrease sampling frequency because of the needed accuracy. So that is not an option.

I'm not exactly sure of how I can accomplish the two write cycles except to increase the SRAM write frequency to something ridiculous like 80 MHz. Another idea of mine was to simply just use two SRAMs instead of one, but this seems terrible inefficient.

So it all boils down to the following two questions:

- Is a CPLD capable of doing such high-speed logic? (80MHz and up) **I have the fear I will experience clock-skew inside the CPLD**: I can't test a CPLD because I don't have the adequate equipment to generate such high-speed signals.
- Is this circuit / idea even feasible or already too ''complex''? Are there easier solutions to my problem?

Comment: Tried 40-bit SRAM yet?

Comment: By my reckoning, 2*20MHz is 40MHz, not 80MHz. Storing increment rather than absolute value may allow you to fit inside 32 bits, then accumulate them in software when you read out. If you filtered your input signals to have sloping edges, then used an ADC, you could reduce your sample rate by several orders of magnitude, and still get the same accuracy and resolution.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is this a thing?

Comment: @user44635 I don't know what you mean with storing an increment value instead of an absolute one.

Comment: It's a *little* exotic, but there are a couple of suppliers.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams hrm :D I'll have a look at it, thanks.

Comment: If you're saving a value on *every* clock edge, you don't need timestamps for every value, just the first of them.

Comment: @pjc50 Ah now I understand but for memory space reasons I only write to the memory if an edge on one of the 16 channels occurred.

Comment: Just an aside, I've near seen a circuit before that stored measurements directly into a RAM without going through a µC as an intermediary.  Pretty neat idea.  I'll have to remember it.

Comment: @tcrosley thanks for letting me know :) I feel honored.

Comment: The delta between 2 timestamps will have fewer bits than either timestamp itself. However I like the comment that suggests storing an absolute timestamp on each recevied edge, then you only have a handful of values to store.

Comment: You focus on technical implementation, and do not consider cost of implementation. It may easily appear that using 2 identical SRAMs, while causes waste of some memory bits, will be the best from component cost perspective, from further development perspective (e.g. reading and processing collected data), and from scalability perspective.